# Wörter mit vielen Anagrammen

Tags: dictionary, curiosity

Ich bin auf der Suche nach Wörtern mit möglichst vielen Anagrammen. Im Optimalfall sollten die Wörter nicht mehr als zwölf Buchstaben haben und die Anagramme sollen Wörter mit der gleichen Anzahl Buchstaben sein ("Geburt - Betrug - Erbgut" ist also in Ordnung, "Belieben - Lebe Bein - Eben Blei" nicht).
Hat jemand einen Link zu einer Liste mit Wörtern mit mindestens 2 Anagrammen?
Ich freue mich auch über einzelne Wörter mit vielen Anagrammen.

Comment: Wenn ich mein offline-Wörterbuch utf-german (Linux) befrage komme ich allein für genau 12stellige Wörter auf die Anzahl von knapp 40.000 Einträgen. Ich würde mir so ein offline-Wörterbuch suchen und dann ein Programm schreiben, welches jedes Wort auf die sortierte Liste seiner Buchstaben mapped, dann nach Mapping gruppieren und nach der Größe der Gruppen sortieren. Kannst Du programmieren?

Comment: Ich bitte darum, dann hier auf jeden Fall eine Liste solcher Wörter zu publizieren. So was kann man immer brauchen. Mir fällt jetzt nur was Bulgarisches ein: лебед (Schwan) --> дебел (dick). Falls das jemanden interessieren sollte.

Comment: Vielleicht hilft auch das hier weiter? - https://www.wort-suchen.de/anagramm-generator/

Comment: Frage: Wie willst du mit äöü umgehen? Darf das in ue etc. aufgelöst werden? Die oben verlinkte Maschine gibt für *ERBGUT* nämlich auch *BUERGT* zurück. Und was ist mit Kasusendungen? *STERNTALER* --> *ELTERNRATS*.

Comment: In meiner Liste, die ich vergaß zuvor zu Kleinbuchstaben zu vereinheitlichen, konnte ich mit 2 dichten Zeilen Scala bei 12 Zeichen maximal 5 Anagramme finden: (ansteigender, eingesandter, eintragendes, gastierenden, stagnierende, tangierendes).

Comment: @userunknown  Cool!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Naja, sammeln wir halt

*Dies ist ein Community Wiki, jeder kann beitragen.*

###Anagramme mit drei oder mehr Lösungen

- Länge 12:
- ansteigender, eingesandter, eintragendes, gastierenden, stagnierende, tangierendes
- entscheidern, entsichernde, scheiternden, schneiderten, schreitenden, streichenden
- Länge 11:
- absuchender, ausbrechend, bauschender, berauschend, brauchendes, schraubende
- Länge 10:
- tischreden, richtendes, scheiternd, schneidert, schreitend, sichtender, streichend
- scheiterns, schreitens, streichens, erscheinst, erschienst, estnischer, sichersten
- besenstiel, liebesnest, stielbesen
- Länge 9:
- enterichs, tierchens, entsichre, erscheint, erschient, reichsten, scheitern, schreiten, sicherten, streichen
- riesenrad, rasierend, radierens, reisrande
- besenrein, beinernes, siebenern
- Länge 8:
- ersteigt, erstiegt, geistert, gerietst, giertest, steigert, stetiger
- Länge 7:
- biester, bieters, triebes, bereist, bereits, breites, siebter
- eiferst, feierst, freiste, reifste, riefest, steifer, streife
- streich, striche, reichst, riechst, schreit, schriet, sichert
- leitens, stielen, einlest, leisten, nieselt, seilten, steilen
- leister, leiters, teilers, ereilst, rieselt, steiler, sterile
- Länge 6:
- ester, resten, sernet, sterne, trense, tresen, ernste, ersten
- scheit, stiche, teichs, tische, eichst, seicht, sichte, siecht
- Länge 5:
- stiel, stile, eilst, liest, liste, seilt, steil, teils
- Länge 4:
- heer, rehe, eher, ehre
- demo, dome, mode, odem
- akts, skat, task, stak
- elke, klee, ekel, ekle
- beil, blei, leib, lieb
- elis, siel, lies, seil
- atem, team, amte, atme
- bier, brei, brie, rieb
- adel, deal, adle, lade
- helm, mehl, lehm
- Länge 3
- sau, usa, aus # USA ist natürlich eine Abkürzung
- ewg, gew, weg # EWG und GEW auch
- eid, ide, die # IDE:=Integrated Development Environment?
- ort, tor, rot
- eis, sei, sie
- nsu, sun, uns # NSU:=Automarke,Terrorgruppe; SUN := Firmenname?
- ard, rad, dar # ARD Rundfunksender
- Länge 2
- ad, da # ad: ad infinitum - ad 3 - gebräuchlich, aber Latein
- he, eh # he: Ausruf, auch fragwürdig, nicht vom Programm vorgeschlagen: an/na

Da mir die Länge von 12 Zeichen recht willkürlich erschien und aus ungerichteter Neugier probierte ich auch längere Worte. Sensationelles kam dabei nicht zustande, maximal folgende Quartette:

- länger als 12 Zeichen
- christlichere, ersichtlicher, reichlichster, richterliches
- retuschierten, unerreichtest, unterschreite, unterstreiche
- datenbereichs, abschreitende, abstreichende, entscheidbare
- entscheiderin, einrichtendes, einschreitend, einstreichend
- einschreibender, niederschreiben, niederschrieben, reinschreibende

Die Wortkomposition im Deutschen erlaubt natürlich sehr viele Wörter, die aus mehreren Wörtern zusammengesetzt sind und sehr oft nicht in Wörterbüchern aufgenommen werden, bei mir beispielsweise Holztisch, Metalltisch, Stahltisch, Glastisch, Kristallglastisch, Bergkristallglastischbein usw., um die Problemlage nur tangential anzureißen.

###Lexemische Anagramme

Anagramme, die im Wörterbuch stehen könnten - also Flexionsformen ausgeschlossen.

- besenstiel, liebesnest
- tastenfee, fastentee
- mehl, lehm, helm
- heer, ehre, rehe, eher
- bier, brei, brie
- beil, blei, leib, lieb
- stiel, liste, steil, teils

###Anagramme aus dem "Gemischten Doppel"

"Gemischtes Doppel" war eine Rubrik im "Süddeutschen Magazin", die Anagramme in scherzhafter Weise mit Illustrationen versah. Auf diese Weise wurden auch "weit hergeholte" Anagramme plausibel, die Neologismen verwendeten wie *Krötenleiber --> Klötenreiber* und *Prinzgemahl --> Minzgeprahl*. Aufbauend auf der Sammlung solcher Anagramme in der Zeitschriftenrubrik wurde später ein Gesellschaftsspiel gleichen Namens mit Bildkarten auf den Markt gebracht (ein Memory-Spiel mit Anagrammen). Die folgenden Beispiel stammen aus der Zeitschrift bzw. vom Spiel.

- Rumäne, Muräne
- Krötenleiber, Klötenreiber
- Prinzgemahl, Minzgeprahl
- Blutrache, Brutlache
- Heidekraut, Kreidehaut
- Mastferkel, Fastmerkel
- Schaumbaden, Baumschaden
- Brockhause, Hockbrause
- Weinstand, Steinwand
- Retromöhre, Metroröhre
- Sternfeuer, Fernsteuer
- Freilandeier, Eilandfreier
- Richtungsding, Dichtungsring

Pluriverbale Anagramme aus der gleichen Quelle

- Pizza mit Nudel, Nizza mit Pudel
- Sauwagen, Wau sagen
- Denken und lösen, Lenken und dösen
- Kopf oder Zahl, Zopf oder Kahl

Phonetische (nicht orthographische) Anagramme

- Juristen tagen, Touristen jagen
- Fair versöhnen, sehr verföhnen

Comment: Die Abkürzungen in 3 sind natürlich heikel. Gehört ein engl. Firmenname (SUN) in ein dt. Wörterbuch? VIelleicht gibt es weiteren Gebrauch der Abkürzung SUN? Ich habe jeweils nur die längsten Listen aus Anagrammen pro Wortlänge ausgewählt.

Comment: Abkürzungen bei 2 Buchstaben und römische Zahlen (ix, xi) habe ich rausgelassen.

Comment: Helm - Mehl - Lehm

Comment: @BernhardDöbler  Ich hab das Mehl in die Liste eingefügt (und außerdem meine ursprünglichen Funde (Besenstiel, Riesenrad, Besenrein) in UserUnknowns computergenerierte Liste eingefügt)

Comment: Ich weiß nicht inwieweit diese Liste sinnvoll ist, da (wenn man Flexionsformen zulässt) man alleine für Wörter mit 4+ Buchstaben auf über 2500 Einträge käme, wenn man die erstbeste frei verfügbare Wortliste als Basis nimmt. - Nach den Wörtern aus dem Bereich der gemischten Doppel war auch teilweise gar nicht gefragt.

Comment: Die Boxer aus der MEISTERKLASSE zerschlugen sich zu KLEISTERMASSE und aus dem ganzen MASSENKLEISTER erhob sich dann der KLASSENMEISTER...

Answer (score 3):

nach meinem Python Programm ist das Wort mit den meisten Anagrammen:
Einers, Einser, eisern, Eisner, Nieser, reines, reisen, Riesen, seiner, Serien, Sirene, Serine (insgesamt 12 Anagramme)

Comment: Könntest Du das Programm und die Datenbasis veröffentlichen? Z. B. auf GitHub.